# 0xFFFF needs cast to short?

Tags: java, android, types

I'm developing an Android 2.3.3 application with Java.

I have the following code:

`short CRCAux = 0xffff;`

I get a warning in eclipse that I have to cast this value to short:

`short CRCAux = (short) 0xffff;`

I'm migrating an iOS application to Android, and in iOS, `CRCAux` is `UInt16`.

Why the compiler needs to cast that value to short? Is short a signed int 16bit data type or not?

Comment: Yes, `short` is a signed 16 bit value. 0xffff is too big a value to fit into a `short`. Luckily there *is* an unsigned 16 bit type in Java: `char`. (But some might argue that using `char` for numeric values is a bit of an abuse of the type).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have another question: Can I use short as an iOS UInt16?

Comment: And if I use `char` I don't need a cast. Why?

Comment: Eh.  You can use `short` as an unsigned 16-bit int, as long as you pay attention to which operations differ for signed and unsigned (not many of them), and convert accordingly.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I don't think so, because an unsigned type has a bigger positive range than a signed type. In other words: imagine an signed data type with two bits. It will accept (1, -1) values. The unsigned version will accepts (3, 0) values. If assign 3 to the signed version I will lose precision, isn't it?

Comment: Eh?  There's a one-to-one mapping, of course; to take signed to unsigned, subtract `2^16` from values greater than or equal to `2^15`.  With that embedding, signed addition is equivalent to unsigned addition; signed multiplication is equivalent to unsigned; the only operations with differences are division, mod, `>`, `<`, and going to/from strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Literals like 0xFFFF are presumed to be of type int by the java compiler. So its very correct you get the warning here, since the int value 0x0000FFFF does not properly fit into the short (the compiler can not know that you do not care about the truncation of the upper zeros in this special case).

In this case, if you write the 16 bit value as signed value, the compiler will accept it without cast:

> short CRCAux = -1;

The short type can be used to store the value of an uint16 (16 bits twos complement are just 16 bits after all, its just a matter of interpretation of those bits).

That said, since java assumes those 16 bits to represent a signed twos complement number. You get very different semantics with many operators (shift, multiply/divide and greater/smaller comparisons). Unless you know exactly what you're doing this will most likely break the code you are porting. Char is a better fit in this case since it delivers the desired 'unsigned' behavior.